# Need help removing from a list into another

Tags: python-3.x

Basically what I am trying to do is make a hangman game. Though I'm making a twist in the game. What I want to do is have the program

So if the user inputs "a" as the first try, the game will then find all words with an "a" in them and remove them from the list and so on, meaning you would almost always miss the first 4 vowels. Eventually you would have the program stick with a word because there is no valid word that it could switch to without having a letter already chosen by the user.

My question is, how can I go about making all of the removed words go into a removed list?

```
# HANGMAN
import random

def main():
    num_wrong=0
    word_list=['car', 'road', 'truck', 'dog', 'desk', 'tree', \
               'cat', 'zug', 'acu', 'python']
    left=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l',\
          'm','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x',\
          'y','z']
    let_guessed=[]
    let_unguessed=['a','b','c']

    finished=False
    r=random.randint(0,len(word_list)-1)
    answer=word_list[r]
    current='_'*len(answer)

    show_status(current,num_wrong,left)

    guess=input('Guess a letter: ')
    while num_wrong<6 and not finished: # after 6 you lose
        left.remove(guess)
        if guess not in answer:
            num_wrong+=1
            print(guess,'is not in the word')
        else: # if the guess is correct
            print(guess,'is in the word')
            # modify current

            for z in range(len(answer)):
                # check to see if we have an alphabetic at that spot already
                if answer[z]==guess:
                    current=current[0:z]+guess+current[z+1:]
                    if answer==current:
                        print('You win!')
                        finished=True

        show_status(current,num_wrong,left)
        if not finished:
            guess=input('Guess a letter: ')

def show_status(str1,x,letters):
    for a in str1:
        print(a+' ',end='')
    print('You have made',x,'wrong guesses so far.')
    print('The following letters are still available:')
    str1=''
    for each in letters:
        str1+=each+' '
    print(str1)

main()
```

Comment: You are missing some letters in your question, after "have the program..."

Answer (score 3):

Just make a new list with the words without the letter chosen by the user:

```
word_list = [w for w in word_list if chosen_letter not in w]
```